# What scenarios does calling `clear` at the end of an ssh session protect against?

Tags: ssh, bash

I have noticed that some server configurations put a `clear` command in the default `~/.bash_logout` file, also with the comment "Clear the screen for security's sake". I can see that this behavior is useful if you have a physical TTY and you log out, making room for the next user.

But for SSH sessions this behavior annoys me because I can't see what I did on the remote server after logging out. I could wrap that `clear` command with a check for `$SSH_CLIENT` or `$SSH_TTY` being empty, to avoid the behavior. But first, I'd like to do a risk assessment. Are there attack scenarios or danger of leaking information where it makes sense to automatically clear the screen after ending an SSH session?

The information-leaking scenarios I could think of:

- A casual passer-by looking at my terminal
- Me accidentally screen-sharing a terminal
- An attacker with remote or physical access to my computer somehow being able to access the scrollback buffer of the terminal

Are there other attacks/scenarios that I did not think of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSH sessions were not the intent when this security measure was introduced.

This habit dates back from when text terminals were common, and network logins (over rlogin, not yet SSH) markedly less so. So the concern was that you'd have some confidential information on screen, then you'd log out and walk away from the computer, and a passer-by or the next person using that terminal would see what was left on the screen.

There's no generic reason to clear the terminal on a logout from a remote text session than at any other time. Any attacker who can see your screen after the session can see your local screen as well.

Of course, if you treat your local machine as a terminal and only ever manipulate confidential data on a remote machine that you access over SSH, then clearing the screen on an SSH logout is a reasonable precaution. Clearing the screen from `.bash_logout` is one way to do it (if you use bash as your shell). Closing the terminal emulator would be another way (assuming it doesn't save the scrollback buffer locally to restore it during the next session, but if you manipulate confidential data that you don't want to store locally, you'd better disable this). But even in this unusual case, you still need to trust the local terminal quite a lot — after all you're entering your credentials there, and giving it a way to run remote commands. So it's at most a minor countermeasure providing a small improvement against the threat that the terminal is compromised later.

Ubuntu and Debian and (most of) their derivatives switched to running [`clear_console`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/bash/clear_console.1.en.html) rather than `clear`, so they only clear the screen when logging out from text mode console.
([After](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=331504#15) some [debate](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=72327#155), because arguably it's the job of getty, the program that displays the login prompt in text mode.) See also [a similar question on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451069/why-is-there-a-call-to-clear-console-in-bash-logout).